# Issue with Mercurial repository - Pushed changsets do not appear

Tags: mercurial, repository

I've got a strange issue that's started since I restored everything on the server after a major catastrophe.

I have two repositories, one is just called "default", and the other is the live website.

When I make changes locally on my dev machine, I commit and push those changes to the default repository. I then SSH onto the server, cd to the live website repository and pull the changes from the default repo, onto the live repo.

The issue is, that when I push the changesets, they appear to go out properly, with no errors, and the hg serve window gives the usual GET list of commands running through it, but when I try to pull from the default repository, it says that no changes are found, and if I run hg summary on the default repository, the changesets that I thought had been pushed to it are not there.

Any idea what could be wrong?

I've tried deleting the default repository and re-cloning from live already, it made no difference.

Here's the contents of my .hgrc file for the default repo.

```
[paths]
default = /var/www/example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial is a distributed system, so from what I understand, you have 3 repos that you call local, default and live.

Your usual process seems legit, but since the restore, could there be a mix up of the repo you are initially pushing to? It may not be the default you think it is... Or the mix up is on the repo you are pulling from?

Try using a UI client to help you debug your issue.

Comment: Hi, Vince. Thanks, that seems to be the case, but looking at the server, I cannot find any evidence of it. The server is a remote headless linux server, and as far as I'm aware, there's no UI clients that can connect to remote repositories are there? eg. Tortoise?

Comment: Repositories are simple folders, that you can query using any mercurial client, command-line or graphical. To get the default repo without any client, look at the .hgrc from the remote repo, as you did for yours.